# Two or more static dirs with flatiron

Tags: javascript, express, flatiron.js

I was using express for a long time now. For the next project I need to use flatiron.js.

As a second dependency I use bower for JavaScript lib handling. Now I want to serve my public/ directory and the bower components/ directory to the frontend.

I tried some static file serving libraries, but all off them only serving the fist set directory. I was used to express setting multiple middlewares like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/components', express.static(__dirname + '/components'));
```

Do I have the chance to get this running in flatiron?